# Create hierarchical data from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

I have two tables like this:

```
ProdId ProdName
1      Mike
2      Carol
3      John
4      Marc

OrdId OrdName ProdId
100     Pizza   1
101     Subs    1
102     Calzone 2
102     Sausage 2
102     Beef    2
105     Pork    4
106     Coke    4
```

I need a query to populate a result like this. The hierarchy should be parent and their child and again parent followed by child.

```
MarkerId  MarkerName MarkerParentId
1         Mike       NULL
100       Pizza      1
101       Subs       1
2         Carol      NULL
102       Calzone    2
103       Sausage    2
104       Beef       2
3         John       NULL
4         Marc       NULL
105       Pork       4
106       Coke       4
```

Please help . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has nothing to do with recursion. Basically you can get what you want with [`UNION`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

```
SELECT ProdId as MarkerId, ProdName as MarkerName, NULL as MarkerParentId from t1
UNION ALL 
SELECT OrdId as MarkerId, OrdName as MarkerName, ProdId MarkerParentId from t2
ORDER BY MarkerId, MarkerParentId
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But we need to join and populate markerparentid from Product table (prodid)

Comment: @Sanjukta It makes exactly the output you're after. You don't need to join since you don't use other data than the ID anyway. If you're after a different result you should edit your question with the output you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help.